# syntax issue iterating through array of items in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to post some data to a web service from jQuery:

```
  var jtvals={};
  jtvals['line_items']=[];
  var g={"name":"jon"};
  var h={"name":"joan"};

  jtvals['line_items'].push(g);
  jtvals['line_items'].push(h);

  $.ajax({
    url: '/arc/v1/api/calculate_line_items',
    type: 'POST',
    data: jtvals,
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function(r){
    alert('this is finished');
  });
```

Rails:

```
  def calculate_line_items
    line_items=params[:line_items]
    puts line_items
    puts line_items.count
    puts "DO LOOP:"

    line_items.each_with_index do |tmp_line_item, idx|
        puts "idx:"
        puts idx

        puts "about to give you:"
        puts tmp_line_item
        puts "after giving you:"
```

and the params look like this:

[image]

however, it is erroring out with:

```
  Parameters: {"line_items"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"jon"}, "1"=>{"name"=>"joan"}}}
{"0"=>{"name"=>"jon"}, "1"=>{"name"=>"joan"}}
2
DO LOOP:
idx:
0
about to give you:
0
{"name"=>"jon"}
after giving you:
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer):
  app/controllers/api_orders_controller.rb:41:in `[]'
  app/controllers/api_orders_controller.rb:41:in `block in calculate_line_items'
  app/controllers/api_orders_controller.rb:33:in `each_with_index'
  app/controllers/api_orders_controller.rb:33:in `calculate_line_items'
```

And I'm not sure why it's treating the key of the array as output. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `tmp_line_item` to return `{"name"=>"jon"}` and `{"name"=>"joan"}`, then try:

```
line_items.each_with_index do |(k, tmp_line_item), idx|
  ...
```

Comment: weird, why is that? Is that a Rails issue - I thought it would go in a straight array.

Comment: @timpone Here's a (brief) explanation I found: http://makandracards.com/makandra/27087-iterating-over-a-ruby-hash-and-while-tracking-the-loop-index.  Is that what you're wondering about?